# ASP.NET click event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I have a table of data that I've created edit/save buttons for so the data can be changed. The edit button is what's originally loaded and upon clicking the edit button, the table is reloaded with text fields to change the particular row of data attached to the button and the edit button is replaced with a save button. The edit event works just fine, but when I go to click the save button, the event is not fired. I've inserted breakpoints to verify that the event is not being triggered. I'm thinking there's an issue with the event not being properly matched up with the save button for some reason. Here's a snippet of code. I can post more if this isn't enough info.

```
HtmlTableCell cell5 = new HtmlTableCell();
cell5.Controls.Add(deleteCriteria);
if (editId == criteria.ID)
{
    Button saveCriteria = new Button();
    saveCriteria.Text = "SAVE";
    saveCriteria.ID = "save" + k;
    saveCriteria.CommandName = "" + criteria.ID;
    saveCriteria.Attributes["class"] = "table-button";
    saveCriteria.Click += SaveCriteria_Click;
    cell5.Controls.Add(saveCriteria);
 }
 else
 {
    Button editCriteria = new Button();
    editCriteria.Text = "EDIT";
    editCriteria.ID = "edit" + k;
    editCriteria.CommandName = "" + criteria.ID;
    editCriteria.Attributes["class"] = "table-button";
    editCriteria.Click += EditCriteria_Click;
    cell5.Controls.Add(editCriteria);
 }
 row.Controls.Add(cell5);
```

Comment: You're creating these controls on code behind. Which function are you doing it from (Page_Load)? And are you recreating these controls upon postback?

Comment: I'm calling the function from Page_Init. The EditCriteria_Click event function is just a call to reload the table. Nothing occurs at postback.